# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, liferay-6, portal

I am uploading a picture in a portlet and have checked the size of the image - if greater than 5MB it is supposed to show an alert but in IE (precisely IE9) it does not show an alert insted throw me an error -

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or
>   undefined

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function _ImageUploadService_WAR_ImageUploadServiceportlet_initEditor() {
//if you dont wnat the default text you can remove.

return '';
}

function submitForm() {

if( $("#_ImageUploadService_WAR_ImageUploadServiceportlet_Picture").val() == ""){
    alert("Please check, You have not Filled Required Field!!");
}else{
        var result = confirm("Are you Sure?");

        if (result == true) {
                document._ImageUploadService_WAR_ImageUploadServiceportlet_photoGallery.submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
}

function checkSize(e){
var val = document.getElementById(e);
var sizeInMB = (val.files[0].size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);
if(sizeInMB > 5){
    alert("Attachment Size Exceeds The Allowable Limit!!");
    $("#"+e).val("");
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: What's the line number of the error?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. The error is on line-
var sizeInMB = (val.files[0].size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support the [File API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should probably skip if the File API is not available.

Try in this way:

```
if(val.files) {
    var sizeInMB = (val.files[0].size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);

    if(sizeInMB > 5){
        alert("Attachment Size Exceeds The Allowable Limit!!");
        $("#"+e).val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your `val` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: No it is not null. I put an alert to check value of val it says [objectHTMLInputElement] in the alert.

Comment: Log `val.files` to see whether it defined or not. Like this `console.log(val.files);`